# Android Widgets: onDataSetChanged not called by updateAppWidget()

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have a ListView-based widget running well, and it relies on a JSON web service call to populate itself. I have a refresh button which works great, and forces a reload from the web. I do it by using a custom broadcast which then calls both onDataSetChanged(), then updateAppWidget() in sequence. What I have found is that when Android updates the widget automatically (based on the time interval set it my XML definition), only updateAppWidget() seems to be called, and my onDataSetChanged() function never runs, leading to an updated timestamp (which I update in each updateAppWidget() call), but stale data.

How can I force Android to call or trigger onDataSetChanged() at a given interval?

Comment: Do you ever call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the remote adapter?

Comment: No. When would/should I do that? It seems the auto-update code doesn't give me a callback?

Comment: I would think that, on update, you should have some reference to your adapter (not sure how you want to save this), then can call the notification on it. `onDataSetChanged()` is only called *after* the notification is sent.

Comment: To be clear, in my AppWidgetProvder.onUpdate() I should call AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged with the widget ID and the ID of the ListView to update? Trying that now :)

Comment: That sounds right. If not, you may have to call it directly on the list's adapter. (`myListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`)

Comment: How can I get a reference to my ListView from an AppWidgetProvider though? I have to set things through RemoteViews and can't directly get at the object, or at least haven't found a way to.

Comment: That's quite a bit trickier, and I don't seem to have any samples in my projects for that, since it's a remote `ListView`... should I take, by that question, that `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` didn't work?

Comment: I'll find out in a bit--the minimum refresh cycle is 30 minutes for Android widgets. 32 minutes have passed with no update, so not looking good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out I needed to call `AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(widgetId, view)` inside my `AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` method.